# Firebase move/copy from one account to another account

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to move firebase database from one account to another account. My client want to move the database to firebase under their account. Is there any way to move from account (sourceaccount@gmail.com) to account (destinationacccount@gmail.com).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to move from the account (sourceaccount@gmail.com) to the account (destinationacccount@gmail.com)?

Yes, you can export the JSON file right from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and then you can import it to the second account. That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. is this option available only for real-time database? I couldn't find it for firestore database

Comment: For Firestore, check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) out. It's different than the Realtime Database.